# Pass custom parameters to IdP via query string

Tags: security, azure, saml

Is there a way to pass additional custom parameters to IdP that is exposed via Windows Azure ACS.

Like some additional action to perform via query string?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. When you call the Home Realm Discovery URL you can pass the parameter "context". The IDP urls that it returns will then have the context included.

So the HRD URL is something like this

```
https://mynamespace.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/metadata/identityProviders.js?   
   realm=myrealm&protocol=wsfederation&version=1.0&context=foo
```

We use this in some our claims aware web applications to "remember" some context when the post from ACS comes back to our relying party application. For more info about the HRD URL look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg185963.aspx) in the section "Home Realm Discovery Metadata Feed".

Oh, and here is a snippet to extract the context when you get the post back from ACS in your RP app:

```
if (Request.Form["wresult"] != null)
{
    var message = WSFederationMessage.CreateFromNameValueCollection(
        FederationMessage.GetBaseUrl(ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Url),      
        ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form) as SignInResponseMessage;
    if (null != message && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message.Context))
    {
        ....
```